# When im using OpenCV with videocapture (python) its show me "please start youcam"

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, camera, video-capture

i want to creat code that can understand faces and my webcam is connected by USB cable (logitech) and my computer is windows 8 hp
code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# multiple cascades: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades

#https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
#https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #this line, i guss that its in the input(0)

while 1:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)

    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml` `haarcascade_eye.xml` and your `.py` not in the same folder.

You must add the path of `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml`
and `haarcascade_eye.xml` into the codes.
For example, this is my codes

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/wxh/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
```

If in the same folder, you do not change the codes.

Then you use the USB, maybe you can change `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` into `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)`.

Last, the codes you submit are right. I can run.

This is my first answer in StackOverflow. I hope these words can help you.